# How to use the displaymath environment within a table?

Tags: tables, math-mode

I am trying to use the **cases** construct **within a table**. I tried to follow [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113107/17444). When I copy paste the entire example, it compiles without an error.

But when I try to reproduce it, I get immediately into trouble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
\[ e \]    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> Bad math environment delimiter [ e ].

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your example and the one you refer to from [how-to-add-equation-with-cases-inside-the-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113105/how-to-add-equation-with-cases-inside-the-table/113107#113107) is that you are trying to put a displayed equation into a "centred" table cell whereas the example puts one inside a "paragraph" in a tabular environment.

You either need to use a `p`-cell in your `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}}
\hline
\[ e \]    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

*OR* you can use a normal (centred) cell with in-line mathematics that you explicitly typeset in `\displaystyle`:

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline
\(\displaystyle f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x=1,\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\)
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Of course, you could also leave the `\displaystyle` out here.

(Btw, here I am assuming that you have loaded the `amsmath` package for the `\text` command.)