# Removing extra vertical space when using cases in a table environment

Tags: tables, equations, cases

I have a table which has `cases` in one of the columns as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113105/how-to-add-equation-with-cases-inside-the-table). The issue I am facing is that the first column has some text, and using `cases` leaves a blank space inline with text from first column. I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/spurious-space-above-align-environment-at-top-of-page-minipage/36963#36963), but is does not solve the problem. Is there any way to get the second column cases horizontally aligned with first column text. Also to remove the vertical space after the cases row and the next row.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}



\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{p{5.5cm}p{5cm}}
Velocity of light in vacuum & $c = \SI{2.998d8}{\meter\per\second}$\\
Gravitational constant & \[ G = \begin{cases} \SI{6.67d-11}{\meter\cubed\per\kilo\gram\per\second\squared} \\
\SI{6.67d-8}{\centi\meter\cubed\per\gram\per\second\squared}\end{cases} \] \\
Acceleration of free fall & $ g = \SI{9.807}{\meter\per\second\squared}$ \\\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is because you use a display equation: `\[ ... \]`. If you use `$ ... $` you will have it inline, just like the rest of it. (You will have to make the column a bit wider, e.g. `p{5.5cm}`, to have it in one line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

- as mentioned @Οὖτις, math should be inline
- off-topic:

  - you  use old (version 2) `siunitx` sintay. I suggest to use new, introduced by package version 3 (see MWE below)
  - simpler table code you can get by use of the `tabularray` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, 
                booktabs, 
                siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {l X[l, mode=math]},
                      rowsep=3pt} % 5pt. pw desired bigger vertical distance between math terms
Velocity of light in vacuum 
    & c = \SI{2.998d8}{\meter\per\second}           \\
Gravitational constant 
    & G = \begin{cases} 
        \qty{6.67e-11}{\meter\cubed\per\kilo\gram\per\second\squared} \\
        \qty{6.67e-8}{\cm\cubed\per\gram\per\second\squared}
          \end{cases}                               \\
Acceleration of free fall 
    & g = \qty{9.807}{\meter\per\second\squared}    \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer about SIunitx.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

This is possible with `nicematrix`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcolumntype{e}{@{$\mspace{\thickmuskip}$}c@{$\mspace{\thickmuskip}$}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \everymath{\displaystyle}
        \begin{NiceArray}[cell-space-limits=1.1pt]{p[l]{5.5cm} r e l}
            \text{Velocity of light in vacuum}
            & c
            & =
            & \SI{2.998d8}{\meter\per\second}
            \\
            \text{Gravitational constant}
            & G
            & = 
            &
            \begin{cases}
                \SI{6.67d-11}{\meter\cubed\per\kilo\gram\per\second\squared} \\
                \SI{6.67d-8}{\centi\meter\cubed\per\gram\per\second\squared}
            \end{cases}
            \\
            \text{Acceleration of free fall}
            & g
            & =
            & \SI{9.807}{\meter\per\second\squared}
        \end{NiceArray}
    \end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```